# Cannot fetch data from Nodejs backend to React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, mern

I'm building MERN stack CRUD with goolge login

I'm running my server on port:3001
and frontend on port:3000

```
  getAll() {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:3001/jobs")
  }
```

try to fetch data with session loggedin

```
router.get("/", util.isLoggedin, (req, res) => {
  Job.find()
    // .populate("author")
    .limit(20)
    .sort({ jobId: -1 })
    .then((jobs) => res.json(jobs))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error:" + err))
})
```

```
const util = {}

util.isLoggedin = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next()
  } else {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
    res.redirect("/")
  }
}

module.exports = util
```

I can retrieve the data only on the server side, not frontend.
what can be the solution?

source code:
https://github.com/jamespark89/mern-communitywebsite

Comment: *I can retrieve the data only on the server side, not frontend*. Are you getting any errors, or is the API working on postman or other tools?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are not awaiting your promise..

```
async getAll() {
    return await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/jobs")
  }
```

Comment: still same issue, I got an error after adding `util.isLoggedin`.
`
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
`

Comment: Error Code is 404 - please check your server is running and also test the api endpoint in postman.. it seems like apiendpoint is not correct or not running..

Comment: I can connect to "http://localhost:3001/jobs/" directly, but cannot fetch witih axios.
I guess the frontend req doens't include the session login info, so server doesn't authorize the fetching, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: If the issue is unauthorized .. then the error code would be 401..

Comment: I just added
"axios.defaults.withCredentials = true"
and fixed...
Thanks for the hlep

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
getAll() {
   return axios.get("http://localhost:3001/jobs")
}
```

with

```
async getAll() {
  return await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/jobs")
}
```

Comment: still same issue, I got an error after adding "util.isLoggedin".

`AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

Comment: I can connect to "http://localhost:3001/jobs/" directly, but cannot fetch witih axios.
I guess the frontend req doens't include the session login info, so server doesn't authorize the fetching, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your get request as an async function I usualy do that:

```
router.get("/", util.isLoggedin, async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const res = await Job.find()
     // .populate("author")
    .limit(20)
    .sort({ jobId: -1 })
    res.status(400).json({ res })
   } catch(err) {
     res.status(400).json("Error:" + err)
   }
})
```